# Evaluate the triple integral $\iiint_E x\,dV$ where $E$ is bounded by the paraboloid $x=4y^2+4z^2$ and the plane $x=4$.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry

> Evaluate the triple integral
>   $$\iiint_E x\,dV$$
>   where $E$ is bounded by the paraboloid $x=4y^2+4z^2$ and the plane $x=4$.

I have been analyzing the part of my book where it evaluates triple integrals for paraboloids non stop, but I can't seem to figure out the method for setting it up. (and solving) I have a feeling one of the integrals will be the paraboloid given as an upper bound and the plane given as a lower bound, but I'm not sure how to get the other bounds without having to manually graph a bunch of points till i can see where everything intersects. I remember setting equations to each other to get intersections but I'm not sure how to apply that here. If someone could show me a detailed explanation of how to set this up (and solve) it would help a lot. Thanks.

Edit:

I have a feeling I'm supposed to put for my outer integral $x$ is from $0$ to $4$, and my inner integrals I use the $\pm$ solutions for $y$ and $z$. Is that right? But I'm not sure how to solve it from here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, integrating along the axis of the paraboloid is a good idea:
$$\int_E x\,dV=\int_{x=0}^4x \left(\int_{E_x}dydz\right) dx$$
where $E_x=\{(y,z):4y^2+4z^2\leq x\}$ which is a disk of radius $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with that integral, and I'm not sure I can take it from there.

Comment: @2316354654 Does it look better now?

Comment: i might just be really tired and forgetting some stuff.

Comment: @2316354654 The inner integral $\int_{E_x}dydz$ is the area of $E_x$.

Comment: ok. can you tell me how you got a disk of radius $1/2√x$

Comment: $4y^2+4z^2\leq x$ is equivalent to $y^2+z^2\leq R^2=(\sqrt{x}/2)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Change coordinates from $x\to z\to x$ in this case the shape remains the same:
$$z=4y^2+4x^2~~~,~~~z=4$$
Then use substitution [cylindrical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cylindrical_coordinates).

Comment: this homework problem was from the section before cylindrical coordinates

Comment: No matter. You can apply Cartesian coordinates as well .